# grok regex parsing not matching a log. when specifying a group as optional, but not the last group

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

Example:

> info: 2014-10-28T22:39:46.593Z - info: an error occurred while trying
>   to handle command: PlaceMarketOrderCommand, xkkdAAGRIl. Error:
>   Insufficient Cash #userId=5 #orderId=Y5545

pattern:

```
> %{LOGLEVEL:stream_level}: %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} -
> %{LOGLEVEL:log_level}: %{MESSAGE:message}
> (#userId=%{USER_ID:user_id})? (#orderId=%{ORDER_ID:order_id})?
```

extra patterns used:

```
USER_ID (\d+|None)
ORDER_ID .*
ORDER_ID_HASH \s*(#orderId=%{ORDER_ID:order_id})?
USER_ID_HASH \s*(#userId=%{USER_ID:user_id})?
MESSAGE (.*?)
```

Works fine:
 removing the optional last orderId also works

> info: 2014-10-28T22:39:46.593Z - info: an error occurred while trying
>   to handle command: PlaceMarketOrderCommand, xkkdAAGRIl. Error:
>   Insufficient Cash #userId=5

but if I keep the orderId and remove the userId then I get a "no match"

> info: 2014-10-28T22:39:46.593Z - info: an error occurred while trying
>   to handle command: PlaceMarketOrderCommand, xkkdAAGRIl. Error:
>   Insufficient Cash #orderId=Y5545

Also the user_id group is ending with a ? as an optional group..

working with the [grok debugger in heroku](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com):

Is this a bug? (logstash 1.4.2) missing something with the regex? (more probable.. but what?)

I looked at the [regex lib grok is using](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt) and looks this syntax supposed to work. It does work for the last group (orderId) but not for the one before..

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You are forcing a space to be before your optional last... you need to do `?`:

```
%{LOGLEVEL:stream_level}: %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} -> %{LOGLEVEL:log_level}: %{MESSAGE:message} ?(#userId=%{USER_ID:user_id})? ?(#orderId=%{ORDER_ID:order_id})?
```